# How to send app referal message using all available messaging apps in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, messaging

I have developed an android app that has a button ,onclick of which it sends a message with a ready template. Before sending the message it prompts the user as to which app they want the message to go from. I have used this in my android app which works absolutely fine:

```
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Check out this app :" + PlayStoreURLtoShare);
```

I have also provided the screenshot below:

[image]

I want to know how can i do the same in Flutter for both Android and iOS devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a package for that in flutter called `share`. You can check it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/share)